# How to auto complete on global variables in Moodle in Netbeans?

Tags: moodle

If you are using Netbeans with Moodle, then the autocomplete doesn't seem to work with the global variables eg: $DB, $PAGE and $OUTPUT.

Answer (score 2):

Discovered there is a very easy solution - just make sure the correct types are declared for each of the global variables in the phpdoc for the function.

eg:

```
/**
 * Returns something fancy
 *
 * @global moodle_database $DB
 * @global moodle_page $PAGE
 * @global core_renderer $OUTPUT
 */
function local_myfancyfunction() {
    global $DB, $PAGE, $OUTPUT;
    ...
```

Now autocomplete will work by simply typing $DB-> for example.